# How to set "enterprise" user attribute in Box?

Tags: box-api

I have the developer account and I see in docs https://developers.box.com/docs/#users-update-a-users-information that the user's "enterprise" attribute can be updated.

I tried it and I was able to update enterprise attribute to null value, but when I sent CURL request using the actual user's enterprise values (id,name,type), I get 403 - "Access denied - insufficient permission" message. I tried also set using id only and some combinations but the message stays the same.

Therefore I want to ask, can be user's "enterprise" attribute set to other values than null? How? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you have a developers account, then you can go into the administrative console, and update a few things about your Enterprise, which will then show up in the /users/me  or /users/id details if you request them.  Enterprise is an optional field on the user and requires you to ask for it via the ?fields=  mechanism.